# Spring MVC&Freemarker - new session every request?

Tags: java, spring, session, attributes, freemarker

I've created simple web app with registration&login based on sessions in Spring MVC 3, which fully worked when I was using JSTL to display values.
Then, I've added Freemarker and something gone wrong. There's new UserSession object created for every request, so I can't store information.

Some code:

dispatcher-servlet.xml:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.revicostudio.web" />
<mvc:annotation-driven />

<bean id="freemarkerConfig" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerConfigurer">
  <property name="templateLoaderPath" value="/WEB-INF/ftl/"/>
    <property name="freemarkerVariables">
      <map>
        <entry key="xml_escape" value-ref="fmXmlEscape"/>
      </map>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerViewResolver">
    <property name="cache" value="true"/>
    <property name="prefix" value=""/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    <property name="exposeSpringMacroHelpers" value="true"/>
    <property name="exposeRequestAttributes" value="true"/>
    <property name="exposeSessionAttributes" value="true"/>
    <property name="exposePathVariables" value="true"/>
</bean>

<bean id="fmXmlEscape" class="freemarker.template.utility.XmlEscape"/>
```

IndexController:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/index")
public class IndexController {

    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getIndex(Model model, UserSession userSession) {
        model.addAttribute("userSession", userSession);
        return "index";
    }

    @ModelAttribute("userRegisterCredentials")
    public UserRegisterCredentials getUserRegisterCredentials() {
        return new UserRegisterCredentials();
    }

    @ModelAttribute("userLoginCredentials")
    public UserLoginCredentials getUserLoginCredentials() {
        return new UserLoginCredentials();
    }
}
```

LoginController:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/login")
public class LoginController {

    @Autowired
    private UsersDatabaseService usersDatabaseService;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String login(
            @ModelAttribute UserLoginCredentials userLoginCredentials,
            UserSession userSession,
            final RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes)
    {
        int failedLoginAttempts = userSession.getFailedLoginAttempts();

        if (failedLoginAttempts < LoginConfig.maxLoginTries ||
                System.currentTimeMillis()-userSession.getFailedLoginsWaitTimeStart() > LoginConfig.failedLoginsWaitMinutes*60*1000) {

            if (usersDatabaseService.isValidPassword(userLoginCredentials.getUsername(), userLoginCredentials.getPassword())) {
                userSession.setUser(usersDatabaseService.getUser(userLoginCredentials.getUsername()));    
                userSession.setFailedLoginsWaitTimeStart(System.currentTimeMillis());
            }
            else {
                failedLoginAttempts++;

                if (failedLoginAttempts == LoginConfig.maxLoginTries) {
                    redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("error", 
                            "You've entered invalid username or password more than "
                            + LoginConfig.maxLoginTries + " times. Try again in "
                            + LoginConfig.failedLoginsWaitMinutes +" minutes.");
                }
                else { 
                    redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("error", "Invalid username or password");
                    userSession.setFailedLoginAttempts(failedLoginAttempts);
                    System.out.println(failedLoginAttempts);
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("error", 
                    "You've entered invalid username or password more than "
                    + LoginConfig.maxLoginTries + " times. Try again in "
                    + LoginConfig.failedLoginsWaitMinutes +" minutes."); 
        }

        return "redirect:/";
    }
}
```

UserSession.java:

```
@Scope("session")
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor 
public class UserSession {
    private User user;

    private int failedLoginAttempts;
    private long failedLoginsWaitTimeStart;
    private long created = System.currentTimeMillis();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was fixed by removing "UserSession userSession" parameter from getIndex() method. Dunno why it caused the problem..